# Zod: Parse external JSON file

Tags: json, typescript, validation, zod

I'm trying to parse an external JSON file with [zod](https://zod.dev/):

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { z } from "zod";

const schema = z.object({
    foo: z.string()
});

// "data.json" contains "{ "foo": "bar" }"
const rawData = readFileSync('data.json');

const dataInline = schema.parse({ "foo": "bar" }); // works
const dataExternalJSON = JSON.parse(rawData);      // works
const dataExternalZod = schema.parse(rawData);     // error
```

`dataInline` works as expected, and `dataInline["foo"]` will return `"bar"`. `dataExternalJSON` seems to work as well.

However, `dataExternal` throws the following error:

```
ZodError: [
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "object",
    "received": "string",
    "path": [],
    "message": "Expected object, received string"
  }
]
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with how `readFileSync` encodes the data it reads.

I tried:

- using different methods to read the file, without success.
- searching for examples of zod usage with `readFile` functions, but couldn't find any.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Alas, it seems the solution was right there:

```js
const dataExternalZod = schema.parse(JSON.parse(rawData));
```

Comment: This was driving me crazy, funny thing is that it works fine locally, the JSON is parsed perfectly fine by my APIs middleware, but when uploaded to a third-party context, it suddenly fails to do the parsing in the middleware... Thanks!