# Is Zod able to parse content of JSON files?

Tags: zod

This might be a duplicate of [Zod: Parse external JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75556846/zod-parse-external-json-file)

---

I have a function that expects a JSON string and parses it to a given type, inferred by a Zod schema

```
const createConfigurationFromJson = (content: string): Configuration => {
  const rawConfiguration = JSON.parse(content);

  return configurationSchema.parse(rawConfiguration);
};
```

This function might throw if the JSON content is invalid JSON or Zod throws a parse error. Without using another third party library, is it possible to let Zod parse the JSON string? So I can be sure there can only be a Zod error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it completely in zod, then make a [custom schema](https://zod.dev/?id=custom-schemas) that returns `true` if it's valid json, otherwise `false`. Then, before you can send that to the `configurationSchema`, you need to [transform](https://zod.dev/?id=transform) the string `content` to an object. You can use [`.pipe`](https://zod.dev/?id=pipe) to pass that to `configurationSchema`.

```js
const configurationSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string(),
  version: z.string(),
  description: z.string(),
});

type Configuration = z.infer<typeof configurationSchema>;

const createConfigurationFromJson = (content: string): Configuration => {
  return z
    .custom<string>((data) => {
      try {
        JSON.parse(content);
      } catch (error) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }, "invalid json") // write whatever error you want here
    .transform((content) => JSON.parse(content))
    .pipe(configurationSchema)
    .parse(content);
};
```

(you could optimize this to use the stored value from the first `JSON.parse`, but that's just a premature optimization that isn't going to affect the vast majority of projects)

When tested with

```js
const configuration1 = createConfigurationFromJson(`{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My awesome app"
}`);

const configuration2 = createConfigurationFromJson(`{
  "banana": ""
}`);

const configuration3 = createConfigurationFromJson(`{
  fiadsjfoiajsdoivjdaoij
`);
```

it outputs the success and errors as

```js
configuration1 {
  name: "my-app",
  version: "1.0.0",
  description: "My awesome app"
}
configuration2 159 |     const json = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
160 |     return json.replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, "$1:");
161 | };
162 | class ZodError extends Error {
163 |     constructor(issues) {
164 |         super();
            ^
ZodError: [
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "name"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
  },
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "version"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
  },
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "description"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
  }
]
 errors: [
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "name"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
  },
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "version"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
  },
  {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "description"
    ],
    "message": "Required"
  }
]

      at new ZodError (/Users/sgunter/code/zod-parse-json/node_modules/zod/lib/index.mjs:164:8)
      at /Users/sgunter/code/zod-parse-json/node_modules/zod/lib/index.mjs:537:30
      at parse (/Users/sgunter/code/zod-parse-json/node_modules/zod/lib/index.mjs:636:14)
      at /Users/sgunter/code/zod-parse-json/index.ts:46:25

configuration3 159 |     const json = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
160 |     return json.replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, "$1:");
161 | };
162 | class ZodError extends Error {
163 |     constructor(issues) {
164 |         super();
            ^
ZodError: [
  {
    "code": "custom",
    "message": "invalid json",
    "fatal": true,
    "path": []
  }
]
 errors: [
  {
    "code": "custom",
    "message": "invalid json",
    "fatal": true,
    "path": []
  }
]

      at new ZodError (/Users/sgunter/code/zod-parse-json/node_modules/zod/lib/index.mjs:164:8)
      at /Users/sgunter/code/zod-parse-json/node_modules/zod/lib/index.mjs:537:30
      at parse (/Users/sgunter/code/zod-parse-json/node_modules/zod/lib/index.mjs:636:14)
      at /Users/sgunter/code/zod-parse-json/index.ts:55:25
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a package for that. In theory, such a package would do barely more than what you're already doing.

Maybe you could surround the json parsing with a try catch block, and turn the generic error into a zod error?